# moving plone or recovering data

Tags: migration, ubuntu-9.04, plone

I had a simple plone site running on my Ubuntu 8.10 box, setup by following instructions on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/forum/server/Plone
Now the computer got an Ubuntu 9.04 install from scratch, and I want to get the site up and running. As far as I understand several python libraries from 9,04 are not compatible with plone. I tried installing plon3-site from ubuntu repos, and I got this:

```
$bin/instance start
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/instance", line 103, in ?
    import plone.recipe.zope2instance.ctl
  File "/media/Robocup2009/robocup2009/eggs/plone.recipe.zope2instance-2.7-py2.4.egg/plone/recipe/zope2instance/__init__.py", line 16, in ?
    import zc.buildout
  File "/media/Robocup2009/robocup2009/eggs/zc.recipe.egg-1.1.0-py2.4.egg/zc/__init__.py", line 1, in ?
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
    ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

I have python-pkg-resources installed.

I actually don't care about plone, I just found it easy to use. My site is just photo and video archive of several users, with low traffic but several gigabytes of data. What would you suggest? Is it easier to get plone working  on my box and start my instance(how?), or recover the content from the instance folder(how?) and setup another content management system(which?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the situation by running Ubuntu 8.04 in a virtual machine and downloading all the content from there. This was the easiest way.